# Self defined Javascript function not working as I expected?

Tags: javascript, html

I had developed a LOGO-like basic turtle graphics interpreter a few years back, I wan't to put it on the web (as my cousin keeps bugging me for it). Though I am quite new to HTML, Javascript coding I thought I would give it a try & take this as a learning experience.

The below code is just for the basic UI (my UI looks very ugly and I will clean it up later).

I have written a Javascript function pushCmd which is called onsubmit of the "cmd-form".

```
function pushCmd()
            {   var cmdText = document.forms["cmd-form"]["cmd-text"].value;
                var srcElement = document.getElementById("source-container");
                var srcText = new String(srcElement.innerHTML);
                srcText = srcText.toUpperCase();
                if (srcText.indexOf("NO CODE") != 0)
                {
                    srcText = cmdText;
                }
                else
                {
                    srcText += "<br>" + cmdText;
                }
                srcElement.innerHTML = srcText;
            }
```

The form is declared like below.

```
<div id="command-container">
                                    <form name="cmd-form" action="" onsubmit="pushCmd()" onreset="resetSource()" method="post">
                                        <input type="text" name="cmd-text" size="80">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Send">
                                        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                                        <input type="button" value="Run">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

The pushCmd function should alter the HTML content of the div "source-container" which by default looks like below.

```
<div id="source-container">NO CODE</div>
```

After I submit the first text (say "FWD 100"). The content of the "source-container" should change to "FWD 100". Then If I submit "RT 90", the content should be "FWD 100
RT 90". This is what I expect out of it.

But when I submit the text. The content of the "source-container" changes for just an instant and then again comes back to "NO CODE". Why is this happening, can anyone please point out where my mistake lies?

I tried both get & post methods but the result is the same. I cannot see any errors or warnings in the Javascript console either. I am using Google chrome Version 26.0.1410.63 if that matters (I guess not).

Please let me know if you need any further information or the full HTML source for this.

Comment: since you are new to js, I suggest learning with jQuery. It is easy to learn/use and yet very powerful and can make many things much easier including selecting certain elements or groups of elements, binding events, and animations.

Comment: @smerny...Thanks for the suggestion (no sarcasm). Learning jquery is on my to-do list.

Comment: just my 2 cents, remember to keep trying to learn javascript while you are learning jQuery. can be easy to just learn how to use the framework and not continue to develop an understanding of behind the scenes.

Comment: Contrary to what @smerny tells you, I think it's quite important that you learn JavaScript _before_ jQuery, otherwise you won't have a clue about which parts of your code are jQuery and which parts are just JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is actually submitting to the empty action. An empty action usually ends up refreshing the current page. So your page may be refreshing so fast that it appears to be an instant change of the `source-container` div.

Instead of using a Submit button, try type=button and then set that button's onclick in the javascript. (Note the `id=""` on the Send button in the HTML)

**HTML**

```
<div id="command-container">
  <form id="cmd-form" action="" onreset="resetSource()" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="cmd-text" name="command" size="80" />
    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" value="Run" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="source-container">NO CODE</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function pushCmd()
{
    var cmdText = document.forms["cmd-form"]["cmd-text"].value;
    var srcElement = document.getElementById("source-container");
    var srcText = new String(srcElement.innerHTML);
    srcText = srcText.toUpperCase();
    alert(cmdText);
    if (srcText.indexOf("NO CODE") != 0)
    {
        srcText = cmdText;
    }
    else
    {
        srcText += "<br>" + cmdText;
    }
    srcElement.innerHTML = srcText;
}

document.getElementById('btnSend').onclick = pushCmd;
```

See this codepen as an example of this code: http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/scAJy

Comment: This looks nice. I think I will convert both Send and Reset buttons the way you suggested. And Run button can be used as a submit option.

Comment: @mobbarley This is bad practice. You should always handle the `submit` event when dealing with a form being submitted. What happens when the "Return" key is pressed while a form's textbox is focused? In some browsers, it submits the form...in some, it doesn't.

Comment: I suspected that mobbarley was going to use a different button for actually submitting the form, since what was desired with the Send button was just to update an element on the page without a refresh. I've edited the example to make Run the submit button as mobbarley added. Ian brings up a good point, that hitting enter in a form will submit it. So you'll want to think about how to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because HTML forms submit to the server by sending a new HTTP request which in your case, with the empty action attribute, is similar to refreshing the page in your browser. In order to prevent the browser from performing the default action (submitting the form) you can return `false` from your function, by adding `return false;` as a last line in it:

```
function pushCmd() {
    var cmdText = document.forms["cmd-form"]["cmd-text"].value;
    var srcElement = document.getElementById("source-container");
    var srcText = srcElement.innerHTML.toUpperCase();

    if (srcText.indexOf("NO CODE") !== 0)
    {
        srcText = cmdText;
    }
    else
    {
        srcText += "<br>" + cmdText;
    }
    srcElement.innerHTML = srcText;
    return false;
}
```

Then change your HTML attribute to return the return value of your function from the `onsubmit`:

```
onsubmit="return pushCmd()"
```

Comment: Why mess with `pushCmd`? Just use `onsubmit="pushCmd(); return false;"`

Comment: @Paulpro Not really. What if `pushCmd` is used elsewhere? I know it's not in this code. But if you're **always** returning false, there's no reason to touch the function. If there's some condition that determines whether the form should finally submit, then you obviously need it. Otherwise, it's more readable to have the behavior defined in one place, not two.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `false` from `pushCmd`, and change the `onsubmit` attribute to `onsubmit="return pushCmd();"` otherwise the form will submit itself and refresh the page.

Also, you need to change this line:

```
srcText = "<br>" + cmdText;
```

to:

```
srcText += "<br>" + cmdText;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
srcText = srcText + "<br>" + cmdText;
```

Which means that you want to append `cmdText` to `srcText`. If you don't have `+=`, you basically end up overwriting `srcText` with just `cmdText`.

Comment: hi vivin, did that. Your point is correct but it still does not work.

Comment: @mobbarley Please see my answer, you also need to change your HTML attribute to return the value: `onsubmit="return pushCmd()"`

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain? On the flip side, thanks for making my rep a multiple of 10. That was bothering me.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Paulpro already explained why this doesn't work

Comment: @Ian I don't think that it warrants a downvote; it was an oversight. Corrected at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting the form, so the page is refreshing, setting it back to its original state.

Depending on what you ultimately need, one solution is to prevent the form submission. You can do this with a simple `return false;` at the end of your function.

```
function pushCmd() {
    var cmdText = document.forms["cmd-form"]["cmd-text"].value;

    var srcElement = document.getElementById("source-container");
    var srcText = srcElement.innerHTML;
    srcText = srcText.toUpperCase();

    if (srcText.indexOf("NO CODE") != 0) {
        srcText = cmdText;
    } else {
        srcText = "<br>" + cmdText;
    }
    srcElement.innerHTML = srcText;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably sending the whole page to the server which will cause it to refresh and therefore you will get the same default value back.

To prevent that from happening you can try to use AJAX, which will allow you to send data to server without refreshing the whole page.

one way to prevent your page to submit to the server is to add `return false;` to your function.

```
function pushCmd()
            {   var cmdText = document.forms["cmd-form"]["cmd-text"].value;
                var srcElement = document.getElementById("source-container");
                var srcText = new String(srcElement.innerHTML);
                srcText = srcText.toUpperCase();
                if (srcText.indexOf("NO CODE") != 0)
                {
                    srcText = cmdText;
                }
                else
                {
                    srcText = "<br>" + cmdText;
                }
                srcElement.innerHTML = srcText;
                retrun false;
            }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response, but it is just a local page & I haven't uploaded it to any server yet. There are http-equiv="refresh" meta tags either.

Comment: if you are already using `onsubmit` event, and your code is executing that means your page will submit to the server, so one way to prevent it is to add `return false;`

Comment: You can mark this answer as solution if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `false` from your `onsubmit` event handler to prevent the page from refreshing itself.    When you push the submit button, your event handler fires but then immediately the form is submitted, which loads the page again.  If you return `false` from an event handler, it prevents the default behavior.
`function pushCmd()
            {   var cmdText = document.forms["cmd-form"]["cmd-text"].value;
                var srcElement = document.getElementById("source-container");
                var srcText = new String(srcElement.innerHTML);
                srcText = srcText.toUpperCase();
                if (srcText.indexOf("NO CODE") != 0)
                {
                    srcText = cmdText;
                }
                else
                {
                    srcText = "
" + cmdText;
                }
                srcElement.innerHTML = srcText;
                return false;
            }`

Additionally, you'll need to `return pushCmd()` instead of just `pushCmd()` in your event handler.

Comment: That's not true. It's inconsistent when used with event handlers bound with Javascript. Inline event handlers require `return functionCall();` in addition. Returning false doesn't just prevent bubbling (which doesn't affect this), it prevents the default behavior as well (like submitting)